# Bash script to calculate time difference

Tags: bash

I would appreciate any kind of help.I am a beginner in the bash script.

I am trying to subtract several times from the time of the start to get a list of time in seconds. See my input file how I did. It didn't work, if anyone can help on that, I would appreciate it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# start time

TIME=10:46:20

# recorded time

TIME_Record=(
11:03:00
11:24:00
11:27:00
11:32:00
)


SEC1=`date +%s -d ${TIME}`
SEC2=`date +%s -d ${TIME_Record}`


DIFFSEC=`expr ${SEC2} - ${SEC1}`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to write a good question, you should include the following information: ① What you tried, ② What you expected to observe, ③ What you observed instead.

Comment: I want the results to look like this:    
1000
2260
2440
2740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are just having difficulties to formulate the loop in bash syntax.  Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
START_TIME=10:46:20
TIME_Record=(
11:03:00
11:24:00
11:27:00
11:32:00
)
SEC1=$(date +%s -d "${START_TIME}")
for d in "${TIME_Record[@]}"
do
  SEC2=$(date +%s -d "$d")
  DIFFSEC=$(( SEC2 - SEC1 ))
  echo "$DIFFSEC"
done
```

Comment: Btw, I would call `TIME_Record` → `recorded_times`, `SEC1` → `start_time_seconds`, `SEC2` → `recorded_time_seconds` and `DIFFSEC` → `duration`.

Comment: I will consider that. Appreciate your response